# Enormous amounts of enterprise elastic system indices, while I don't use elastic enterprise search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, elastic-enterprise-search

I currently have 135 shards on two nodes each, which is severly hurting my search performance. When looking at `GET /_cat/shards` I see that most shards come from the enterprise search, while I don't even use that.

For example:

```
.ent-search-actastic-crawler_domains_v6-engine_oid-name-unique-constraint                                                       0 r STARTED         0     225b 10.47.32.112 instance-0000000006

.ent-search-actastic-crawler2_content_metadata                                                                                  0 r STARTED         0     225b 10.47.32.112 instance-0000000006
```

How do I remove enterprise search from my hosted elasticsearch system and free up all these shards?

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended method:**
Remove via `Kibana UI => Enterprise Search => App Search and/or Workplace Search`

```
GET _cat/indices/.ent-search*?v
health status index                                            uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .ent-search-engine-documents-national-parks-demo 5PVo_5BRRIO8-L20eBm8UA   2   0         59            0      278kb          278kb
```

after remove that it will return 0 results.

```
DELETE .ent-search-engine-documents-national-parks-demo
```

or

```
#DELETE .ent-search-* \\ careful, it will remove all indices starting with .ent-search pattern
```

[image]